# what should be the servername of a domain

Tags: domain

let's say i want to host a website on my home. my ISP doesn't block port 80.

1. i got a static ip,
2. registered my domain name,
3. inserted my static ip in the registrar DNS.

Here is the tricky part what should be my servername ? my domain e.g.(superuser.com)

servername should be same as my domain name ? e.g.(superuser.com) OR (machineone.superuser.com)
it can be any name ? e.g. (doesn't matter)

And where should i do this in apache confiig or registrar config ?

Please give me some suggestions ...

Answer (score 2):

Doesn't matter what you call the Server - If your DNS is setup correctly all traffic to the IP at your home will reach your router.  More important is that you need to "forward" or route the traffic for port 80 on the router to your server (whatever you call it) and then simply setup Apache to accept traffic for that domain.

Answer (score 1):

Doesn't matter at all. I typically give servers generic names according to their generic function, something like web-01, db-01, etc. The specific service each server is hosting tend to move around from time to time, so naming servers after the domains they're hosting just tends to complicate future maintenance.